# get specific element and attribute from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I try for  many day, but I cant to do it...

I try to acces to specific XML's node like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESP>
    <ITEM_TAG COUNT ='1'>
        <ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT index = '1'>
            <NAME>TAD-DA</NAME>
            <CODE>54578</CODE>
        </ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT>
        <ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT index = '2'>
            <NAME>TAD-NA</NAME>
            <CODE>54579</CODE>
        </ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT>
    </ITEM_TAG>
</RESP>
```

I want to acces direct to element TAD-DA without using a "for-each".

I try to do is get the value of the first element , like

```
<xsl:value-of select="/RESP/ITEM_TAG COUNT ='1'/ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT index = '1'/NAME" />
```

Sorry for my bad english but I am starting to learn english.

Comment: Some suggestions: (a) You need to explain what output you want to produce. (b) You should show your best attempt, even if it doesn't work. Then we can see where you are going wrong, and help you correct your mistakes. (c) We can't tell what is known about this document and what is unknown. Are you looking for the first element containing "TAD-DA" whatever the element name? Or are you looking for the first NAME element whatever its content? Or something else?

Comment: And why do you say "without using a for-each"? I can't see why you would want a for-each in this case, but why do you have a requirement that you can only use a subset of the language?

Comment: I regret the poor explanation , which is try to get the value of the first element NAME , whatever its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to get the `ITEM_TAG` with `COUNT` of 1, and the `ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT` with an `index` of `, the expression is this

```
ITEM_TAG[@COUNT='1']/ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT[@index='1']
```

Then, you would have a template matching `ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT` where you could get `NAME` node values, for example.

Try this as an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="RESP">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM_TAG[@COUNT='1']/ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT[@index='1']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT">
    <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact, you could simplify it to this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="RESP">
    <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_TAG[@COUNT='1']/ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT[@index='1']/NAME" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to get the value of <NAME>, 
taking the value of the node [ ITEM_TAG ] with COUNT = 1 attribute, [ ITEM_TAG_ELEMENT ] with the attribute INDEX = 1

Comment: thanks Tim this works, but.. when i try to use this solution to make a pdf with Apache FOP I don't know why don't work :(

Comment: Feel free to ask another question on stackoverflow if you are struggling with that.